# Searching in a list of structs with lambda-like syntax in C++

Tags: c++, search, lambda

```
struct Data
{
int Id;
std::vector<int> SomeData
}

std::vector<Data> dataList = ....

int wantedIndex = 11;
std::find(dataList.begin(), dataList.end(), "where dataList.Id == wantedIndex")
```

Is this syntax possible in standard C++ in some way in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Can you use a `map` from the id to the vector instead? Also, just to note, Data, and dataList are terrible names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 comes with support for lambdas:

```
std::find_if(dataList.begin(), dataList.end(), 
             [&wantedIndex](const Data& x) { return x.Id == wantedIndex;});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I am stuck using visual studio 2008

Comment: While not the best answer to the question, it does give a good reply to the title of the post, so might be useful is someone search for the same thing.

Comment: @user1038502 I can cook something up using boost::lamdba/phoenix and a functor if this would be a better fit. Saw the change in requirements just now.

Comment: My project does not have boost, while it would be interesting, it would not help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use C++11. Maybe you can use boost [phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html).

It would be like this:

```
#include <boost\phoenix\phoenix.hpp>
...
std::find_if(dataList.begin(), dataList.end(), 
boost::phoenix::bind(&Data::Id, boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1) == boost::phoenix::val(wantedIndex)));
```

Although I think in your very simple case bind from boost will also do it.

```
std::find_if(dataList.begin(), dataList.end(), boost::bind(&Data::Id, _1) == wantedIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have visual studio 2008 then you cannot use lambda function i guess
The proper way to do is following:

```
int wanted_index = 11;
struct Data
{
int Id;
std::vector<int> SomeData
}
bool find_fun(int i)
{ 
 return i == wanted_index;
}
//std::vector<Data> dataList = ....

std::find(dataList.begin(), dataList.end(), find_fun);
```

You can also use boost bind or std::tr1 bind to have lambda function like syntax.
As it appears from the msdn visual studio 2008 documentation that you can use std::bind() also
see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982702(v=vs.90).aspx

so you can use :

```
bool find_fun1(int i, int wanted_index)
{
  return i == wanted_index
}
int wanted_index = 11;
std::find_if(dataList.begin(), dataList.end(), std::bind(find_fun1,_1,wanted_index));
```

Comment: `find` takes a value not a predicate

Comment: sorry i intended to write find_if

Comment: I think it is, as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01ay7e0y(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I deleted my comment, sorry, you're correct `find_if` is available in VS 2008.